# Swift initializing lazy value

Tags: swift, initialization, lazy-evaluation

I have class

```
struct Word {
  let text : String
  let added: Date
  let willShow: Date
  let folder: Phase
  let bestTranslation: String
  let translationsProvider: ()->[String]
  lazy var allTranslations : [String] = {self.translationsProvider()}()
}
```

and initializer

```
extension Word {
    init(_ definition: Definition, context translationProvider: 
                                               @escaping ()->[String]){
    self.text = definition.text!
    self.added = definition.added!
    self.willShow = definition.willShow!
    self.folder = Phase(rawValue: definition.folder)!
    self.bestTranslation = definition.best?.text ?? ""
    self.translationsProvider = translationProvider
    }
}
```

I'm getting error

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

with description

> 1. 'self.allTranslations.storage' not initialized

How can I fix that?

Comment: Same versions. Extension is located in different file. Can this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this is possibly a compiler bug.  I don't see the same error you are getting, but this will create a Swift compiler segmentation fault 11:

```
struct Test {
  let foo: String
  lazy var bar: String = { return "" }()
}

extension Test {
  init(_ foo: String) {
    self.foo = foo
  }
}
```

Comment: I created an issue on bugs.swift.org, it really seems like compiler bug

Comment: @AlexeyShvachka  You beat me to it!  Do you have a link to the issue?